# Convert array to ActiveRecord::Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, find-by-sql

I am using `find_by_sql` for this query, and it iss returning an array.
I want to do something like `Job.hongkong_jobs.where(status: true)` but I can't because it is an array.

```
 scope :hongkong_jobs, -> { find_by_sql "SELECT DISTINCT(jobs.*) FROM" + Task.near([22.275754, 114.163056], 35.17936816723013, :units => :km).joins(:job).where(jobs: {status: [:open,:new]}).to_sql.split("FROM").last.split("ORDER").first + "ORDER BY start_at ASC" }
```

So my question is : **how can I convert it into an active record object so I can do `.where` within this scope?**

Answer (score 6):

I tried with `Job.where(aray.map(&:id))`, and it's not working for me.

My solution is:

```
Job.where(id: array.map(&:id))
```

This works.

Cheers.

Comment: This should be `Job.find(array.map(&:id))`.

Comment: I think you need to use `where` to return an `ActiveRecord::Relation`. When I use `find` with multiple IDs, I get an array (at least in Rails 6)

Answer (score 1):

Given an `array` of Active Records, you can obtain the ActiveRecord::Relation by first obtaining the `ids` of the records using the `map` function, then use `.where` to fetch them from the model.

In your case:

`Job.where(array.map(&:id))`

Answer (score 0):

1 - Do it in SQL: put it in the SQL query you have above as raw SQL

OR

2 - Do the sorting in ruby: Use `select` on your array to get the records that would match your criterion (all the ones that have a true status)